# status= not working on mx google maps tag exp:mx_google_map:search

Tags: mx-google-map

I want to only show entries with the status of open.

Currently closed entries are also showing when using the following tag

exp:mx_google_map:search

Any ideas if it's possible?

I thought of doing a search:status="open" but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

{exp:mx_google_map:search channel="articles" ...}

{entries}
**{if status == "open"}**

**{/if}**
{/entries}

{/exp:mx_google_map:search}

http://www.eec.ms/user_guide/mx-google-map/tags.html#lv27

> For result ({exp:mx_google_map:search}) addon used channel class , so
>   you can used all Channel tags inside {entries}{/entries} tags.